# Cost of ExecutionContext.Capture() and ExecutionContext.Run(context, work, state)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance

Does anybody know if it is expensive to `ExecutionContext.Capture()` and to  `ExecutionContext.Run(context, work, state)`?

Does it decrease performance and so is recommended to use carefully?

I'm asking since I have an ContextItem where I save Context work and state in to execute later. Since I want to be able to react on an exception that might be thrown while executing work, I have a fallback that is executed if an exceptrion is thrown in work. And I also have final work, that is executed in any case regardlessly if an exception was thrown or not. 
Since I can use an ExecutionContext only once I would have to `ExecutionContext.Capture()` three times for one of these ContextItems...

Or does this sound like a totally wrong approach?

Comment: Well, a downvote without a comment is not helpfull at all...

Comment: @cory nelson so if I can resolve the problem with a lock, it is cheapter?
Honestly I think it isn't fair to say a question isn't good, since none of the questions for Executiocontext at stackoverflow are discussing if it is expensive to use it, neither the pages online I found for this topic. So you say if I don't know something or I don't understand an explanation I shouldn't be asking a question? THen where is the sense of this website?

Comment: Your posted code is all You need. Put a for loop around it with 10 million iterations and check out for yourself. If the cost is ok depends on if you call it so often that it becomes a problem.

Comment: @Alois Kraus Thanks for the advice, I did so, see my answer.

Comment: I'd just point out that there's usually no point about asking about performance in the abstract. You need to set performance goals for your system and then write simple, understandable (and correct) code. You then *measure* the performance and decide whether it meets the goals. If it meets the goals and is simple to understand, don't then re-write it to be less understandable (and potentially less correct) just for "performance".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever True, but you don't even may need to set a performance goal. The architecture, readability and maintainability comes definitely first. Maybe the way I was asking my question was misleading. I was looking more for an advice about how to use ExecutionContext in general - or maybe not to use it at all. My approach of measuring the performance was only the first on the way of finding answers to this topic. (Maybe it was the wrong order of approaching it - but it was interesting and informing.)

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote about this in [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/): "If neither horse is fast enough for your purposes then knowing which is faster is irrelevant. And if both are fast enough then you can base your decision on important factors other than performance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended by @Alois Kraus I ran a test with the following code comparing locking to capturing & lined up excecution:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();
    private static readonly int numberOfItems = 1000000;
    private static readonly int _numberOfIterations = 1000000;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MeasureTimeWithLocking();
        MeasureTimeWithCapuringContext();
        Console.WriteLine();
        MeasureTimeWithLocking();
        MeasureTimeWithCapuringContext();
        Console.WriteLine();
        MeasureTimeWithLocking();
        MeasureTimeWithCapuringContext();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void MeasureTimeWithLocking()
    {
        List<ContextItem> items = new List<ContextItem>();
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
        {
            ContextItem item = new ContextItem();
            item.Work1 = DoSomeWorkWithLock;
            item.Work2 = DoSomeWorkWithLock;
            item.Work3 = DoSomeWorkWithLock;
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(items, (item) =>
        {
            item.Work1(null);
            item.Work2(null);
            item.Work3(null);
        });
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed with locking:           " + stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void MeasureTimeWithCapuringContext()
    {
        List<ContextItem> items = new List<ContextItem>();
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
        {
            ContextItem item = new ContextItem();
            item.Context1 = ExecutionContext.Capture();
            item.Context2 = ExecutionContext.Capture();
            item.Context3 = ExecutionContext.Capture();
            item.Work1 = DoSomeWork;
            item.Work2 = DoSomeWork;
            item.Work3 = DoSomeWork;
        }

        foreach (ContextItem item in items)
        {
            ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context1, item.Work1, null);
            ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context2, item.Work2, null);
            ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context3, item.Work3, null);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed with capturing context: " + stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void DoSomeWork(object ignored)
    {
        Work();
    }


    private static void DoSomeWorkWithLock(object ignored)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Work();
        }
    }

    private static void Work()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfIterations; i++)
        {
            count ++;
        }
    }

    private class ContextItem
    {
        public ExecutionContext Context1 { get; set; }
        public ExecutionContext Context2 { get; set; }
        public ExecutionContext Context3 { get; set; }

        public ContextCallback Work1 { get; set; }
        public ContextCallback Work2 { get; set; }
        public ContextCallback Work3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Results are:

[image]

So if I did this right, capturing & executing lined up is in average round about 5 times more expensive than locking.

To also answer the part of my question:

> Or does this sound like a totally wrong approach?

I read in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx) that

> if you have to know they’re there, either you’re doing something super advanced, or something’s gone wrong.

The article was recommended on SO as the best source if you want to know about ExecutionContext.
After going through it and running some tests with a colleague I realized that I was using ExecutionContext where it didn’t make sense, plus it is less performant then than locks and so it probably also is less performant than other threading functionalities / constructs.